# combn unclasses factor variables

Tags: r, syntax

### UPDATE: FIXED

This is fixed in the upcoming release of R `3.1.0`. From the CHANGELOG:

> `combn(x, simplify = TRUE)` now gives a factor result for factor input
> `x` (previously user error).
> Related to [**PR#15442**](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15442)

---

I just noticed a curious thing. Why does `combn` appear to unclass `factor` variables to their underlying numeric values for all *except the first* combination?

```
x <- as.factor( letters[1:3] )

combn( x , 2 )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "1"  "2" 
#[2,] "b"  "3"  "3"
```

This doesn't occur when `x` is a character:

```
x <- as.character( letters[1:3] )

combn( x , 2 )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
#[2,] "b"  "c"  "c"
```

Reproducible on R64 on OS X 10.7.5 and Windows 7.

Comment: Factors are a huge pain in the *ss in R. Their treatment is woefully inconsistent across functions, and quite hard to get right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is due to the conversion to `matrix` done by the `simplify` parameter. If you don't use it you get:

```
combn( x , 2 , simplify=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] a b
Levels: a b c

[[2]]
[1] a c
Levels: a b c

[[3]]
[1] b c
Levels: a b c
```

The fact that the first column is OK is due to the way `combn` works: the first column is specified separately and the other columns are then changed from the existing matrix using `[<-`. Consider:

```
m <- matrix(x,3,3)
m[,2] <- sample(x)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "1"  "a" 
[2,] "b"  "3"  "b" 
[3,] "c"  "2"  "c"
```

I think the offending function is therefore `[<-`.

Comment: Thanks James, I'll do some digging in the source for `[<-` to see if I can work out what happens (I am not very good at reading the source though - it's heavy going).

Comment: @SimonO101 Good luck, it's a primitive function, and to quote the manual about internal functions: "Only true R wizards should even consider using this function"

Comment: Ha, I thought that was for mucking around with `.Internal`! I promise I will only read. I won't try and cast any incantations!

Answer (score 1):

As Konrad said, the treatment of factors is often odd, or at least inconsistent.  In this case I think the behaviour is weird enough to constitute a bug.  Try [submitting it](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/), and see what the response is.

Since the result is a matrix, and there is no factor matrix type, I think that the correct behaviour would be to convert factor inputs to character somewhere near the start of the function.

Comment: The other commonly encountered weird behaviour is indexing with factors.  Given `x <- factor(letters[1:3])` and `y <- c(c = 9, b = 6, a = 3)`, what is the value of `y[x]`?  Is it the same as `y[as.character(x)]` or `y[as.integer(x)]`?

Comment: I'll try and submit a bug report, but the though scares me! Thanks.

Comment: @SimonO101 -- Sounds like you basically want an additional line of code in `combn()` that does `if(is.factor(r)) r <- as.character(r)` somewhere before the line reading `out <- matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count)`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien well I filed [**bug report 15442**](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15442) anyway. I'll see what happens.

Comment: @SimonO101 -- Congrats [on the success of your bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15442). Well done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Coercing back to a character vector inside the combn command seems to work:

```
 > combn(as.character(x),2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "c"
```

Comment: Or update R to V 3.1 (pre-release). This is fixed in the upcoming release. From the change log: `combn(x, simplify = TRUE)` now gives a factor result for factor input `x` (previously user error).  Related to [**PR#15442**](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15442)